# How to form this SQLite query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two table, one is

```
ItemData(ItemID, ItemName)
```

and other one has few columns.

I can retrieve IDs from second table but I want `ItemNames` corresponding to those iIDs. I used following code but it is returning only one item name:

```
SELECT ItemName
  FROM ItemData
 WHERE ItemID = ( SELECT ItemID
                    FROM StoreItem
                   WHERE StoreId = 3
                     AND Value = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ItemName from ItemData
WHERE ItemID in ( SELECT ItemID from StoreItem WHERE StoreId = 3 AND Value = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your inner query returns more than 1 ItemID then use the `IN` clause -

```
SELECT ItemName from ItemData WHERE ItemID IN ( SELECT ItemID from StoreItem WHERE StoreId =3 AND Value=1)
```